# Add consecutive alphabet letters as object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I want to create an object with the given structure:

```
const questions = [
  {
    id: '1',
    instruction: 'Question1',
    options: {
      'a': 'SomeText1',
      'b': 'SomeText2',
      'c': 'SomeText3'
    },
    correct: ['c']
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    instruction: 'Question2',
    options: {
      'a': 'SomeText1',
      'b': 'SomeText2',
      'c': 'SomeText3',
      'd': 'SomeText4'
    },
    correct: ['a']
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    instruction: 'Question3,
    options: {
      'a': 'SomeText1',
      'b': 'SomeText2'
    },
    correct: ['b']
  }
]
```

I have an arrays containing necessary information to fill this object and create it using `.map()` .

```
const questions = 
[ 'Question1',
  'Question2',
  'Question3'
]

const answers = 
[ 
 'Answer1',
 'Answer2',
 'Answer3'
]

const options = [
   [ 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3' ],
   [ 'Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6' ],
   [ 'Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9' ]
 ]

function toJson()
  const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  const json = questions.map((question, index) => (
    {
      id: index + 1,
      instruction: question,
      options: Object.assign({}, options[index]),
      correct: answers[index]
    }
  ))
}
```

I have only problem with `options` key. As You see I want to have a letters as keys, depending on how many answers question has. 
This function gives me numbers as keys when I use `Object.assign()`, and I don't know how to replace them with letters from `alphabet` array.

EDIT:

So the solution for the `options` key in desired object is:

```
options: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        ...options[index].map((a, i) => ({ [alphabet[i]]: a }))
      ),
```

Now I'm able to create an object with consecutive alphabet letters with assigned answer.

Comment: Can you show us what the `options` variable is?

Comment: Added ```options``` variable. Content is of course irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options[index]` returns an array. It contains values by index. By passing it to `Object.assign`, you add all values by their array index as a string: `"0"`, `"1"`, etc.

If we `map` the array in to a list of `{ "a": option }` first, and spread the result in to the `Object.assign` call, we can change those indexes to the letters you want:

```js
const questions = 
[ 'Question1',
  'Question2',
  'Question3'
]

const answers = 
[ 
 'Answer1',
 'Answer2',
 'Answer3'
]

const options = [
   [ 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3' ],
   [ 'Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6' ],
   [ 'Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9' ]
 ]

function toJson() {
  const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  const json = questions.map((question, index) => (
    {
      id: index + 1,
      instruction: question,
      options: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        ...options[index].map((a, i) => ({ [alphabet[i]]: a }))
      ),
      correct: answers[index]
    }
  ));
  
  return json;
}

console.log(toJson());
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using something like [`zip`](https://30secondsofcode.org/index#zip) and [`objectFromPairs`](https://30secondsofcode.org/object#objectfrompairs) (both snippets from [30secondsofcode](https://30secondsofcode.org), a project/website I am a maintainer of). From the website:

#### zip

> Creates an array of elements, grouped based on the position in the original arrays.
>
> Use `Math.max.apply()` to get the longest array in the arguments. Creates an array with that length as return value and use `Array.from()` with a map-function to create an array of grouped elements. If lengths of the argument-arrays vary, `undefined` is used where no value could be found.

#### objectFromPairs

> Creates an object from the given key-value pairs.
>
> Use `Array.reduce()` to create and combine key-value pairs.

The only extra step I took was to trim each zipped array to the `length` of `options[index]`.

```js
const questions = ['Question1',
  'Question2',
  'Question3'
]

const answers = [
  'Answer1',
  'Answer2',
  'Answer3'
]

const options = [
  ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'],
  ['Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6'],
  ['Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9']
]

const zip = (...arrays) => {
  const maxLength = Math.max(...arrays.map(x => x.length));
  return Array.from({
    length: maxLength
  }).map((_, i) => {
    return Array.from({
      length: arrays.length
    }, (_, k) => arrays[k][i]);
  });
};

const objectFromPairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, [key, val]) => ((a[key] = val), a), {});


function toJson() {
  const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  const json = questions.map((question, index) => ({
    id: index + 1,
    instruction: question,
    options: objectFromPairs(zip(alphabet, options[index]).slice(0, options[index].length)),
    correct: answers[index]
  }))
  console.log(json);
}

toJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

the below should work (i believe)

```
options: alphabet.reduce((acc, letter, i) => {
    let option = options[index][i] || 'DefaultText' + i;
    acc[letter] = option;

    return acc;
```

}, {})

**Edit:** Corrected typos

Comment: Almost, because it returns an array besides an object. It also returns options for all letters in alphabet, even if there's 2 or 3 options for question.
`options: 
     [ [Array],
       [Array],
       [Array],
       a: 'Answer1',`

Comment: opps, that was a typo
`options: alphabet.reduce((acc, letter, i) => {
  let option = options[index][i] || 'DefaultText' + i;
    acc[letter] = option;

    return acc;
}, {})`

that should work. there's obviously the problem in your example that there are too many letters to options so you would get undefined if the default value was not added in as i've done

Comment: Yes, that is kinda working. I put letters up to `e`, because, different questions could have different number of options (it's not fixed). So in object there should be as many `keys` as options for the question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

So the solution for the options key in desired object is:

```
options: Object.assign(
        {}, 
        ...options[index].map((a, i) => ({ [alphabet[i]]: a }))
      ),
```

Comment: Please explain why and how your code solves the problem.